# Object return type is not supported in WCF test client

Tags: wcf

In WCF i have a class which is acting as the return type for all my methods.

```
public class ResponseResult
{
  public object data {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and in **IService** interface i have method declaration like:

```
ResponseResult GetValues(int id);
```

if run the test client GetValues is not available.beside the method name i am getting cross sign on hover it says "*this method is not supported in WCF Test client because it uses mmService.Common.ResponseResult*".

if i remove the property data then it get visible and i want that object property. please help me out.

Comment: what are you returning in `data` field actually?

Comment: data can have any thing like list of class , string value or single class.

Answer (score 0):

Object data type will not work with service client.service client need the serialize data type like list , string , int etc.... it will not actually decide the actual return type of object data type.